Java Annotation @Resource injects Resource also if JNDI names don't match
I was trying to inject a DataSource to my service using the @Resource annotation.
@Resource(mappedName = "PROPERTIES", name = "PROPERTIES") DataSource dataSource;

I'm running the service on a TomEE application server. On the server I have two data source resources available
<tomee>
    <Resource id="DATA" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver  org.h2.Driver
        JdbcUrl     jdbc:h2:~/datadb
        UserName    sa
        Password    sa
        JtaManaged  true
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="PROPERTIES" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JdbcDriver  org.h2.Driver
        JdbcUrl     jdbc:h2:~/properydb
        UserName    sa
        Password
        JtaManaged  true
    </Resource>
</tomee>

In this situation everything works fine and the DataSource with the JNDI name PROPERTIES is injected correctly.
But, if I remove the resource with the id PROPERTIES from the project, the DataSource with the id DATA is going to be injected.
I was expecting that in this case no DataSource is going to be injected and the field dataSource remains null, because there is no DataSource with matching JNDI name. That would also be the behaviour that I would like to have.
Can anybody please explain, because the DataSource with the id DATA is injected?
Do I have some wrong configuration in my project?
Can I somehow add a restriction, that DataSource is only injected on exact match of JNDI name?
Thanks, Michael
